# How to remove indexes of ES to start the new upgraded ES

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I was upgrading Wazuh to a newer version. But the API requires me to upgrade the ES and Kibana too. So I went to upgrade both of that. But unfortunately after installing the packages, the new ES cannot be started. I suspect is the different index format that causes it.

Now I am not able to start the ES, in another word I am not able to curl or issue command to delete it. How can I overcome it?

Now I can see new logs has been created, deorecation.log / index_search_slow.log / index_indexing_slowlog.log etc. But since ES cant be started, these log files are empty.

Error when I start ./elasticsearch in the bin folder:

```
[WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [eta10] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:102) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:169) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.0.jar:7.1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run ES from root user. When you install elasticsearch the user and group 'elasticsearch' will be created. Try to run ES with this user or if your installation method using .deb or .rpm it must have systemd for start the elasticsearch service. just run command '**systemctl start elasticsearch**'

Comment: Hi I am trying to change the data directory to a new one. But now I when I run ./elasticsearch it prompt me this error. Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/elasticsearch-7/nodes/0

Comment: have you set permission and ownership of the directory to the elasticsearch user & group? I think you don't have permission to create directory / files.

Comment: Ok, now temporary I set it to 777 for all to access. Now the script can run but still with error. --> main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
-->  main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling_old" for logger config "root"

Comment: But can the elasticsearch user, I cannot use that account to run ES. It says there is no Home directory. So currently I change all the ES dir and files to user:user.